# AWS - Network Performance doesn't correspond to what it should be as mentioned by aws amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2

Good morning everybody,

I am really trying to understand about AWS Network Performance.

I did a lot of tests and my conclusion is that the speed really doesn't correspond to what it should be as mentioned by AWS amazon.

Well, I created 9 different EC2 on this test. All these instances were created on the same zone (North Virginia), all running on Ubuntu 18.04. ENA: Yes. [AMI - Ubuntu 18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCOtI.png)

Measurement: Speedtest cli

1st instance: **t2.micro (low to moderate) > Down: 488.86Mbps/ Up: 946.49Mbps** 

2st instance: **t2.large (low to moderate) > Down: 940.31Mbps/ Up: 900.47Mbps** 

3rd instance: **t2.xlarge (moderate) > Down: 964.90Mbps/ Up: 942.10Mbps** 

4th instance: **t3.micro (Up to 5 Gigabit) > Down: 4002.90Mbps/ Up: 2844.04Mbps** 

5th instance: **t3a.nano (Up to 5 Gigabit) > Down: 1584.52Mbps/ Up: 1451.76Mbps** 

6th instance: **t3a.small (Up to 5 Gigabit) > Down: 2758.09Mbps/ Up: 2143.01Mbps** 

7th instance: **t3.2xlarge (Up to 5 Gigabit) > Down: 2936.57/ Up: 2733.28 Mbps** 

8th instance: **m5a.large (Up to 10 Gigabit) > Down: 3178.89/ Up: 2291.97Mbps** 

9th instance: **r5n.large (Up to 25 Gigabit) > Down: 4361.71/ Up: 3383.65Mbps**

These measurement results:

[Instances 1-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJxEK.jpg)

[Instances 3-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEV14.jpg)

[Instances 5-6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTjzt.jpg)

[Instances 7-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJne9.jpg)

[Instance 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRx1m.jpg)

Having these results, we can conclude:

- Network Performance:

1. Low to Moderate: The best we can get is almost 1Gigabit. (Down and Up) **Very good speed for low to moderate.**
2. Moderate: Keep about almost 1Gigabit network performance. **That's fine**
3. Up to 5 Gigabit: We can get down/up starting on about 1.5 Gigabit. The fastest I measured was down/up 4002Mbps/2844Mbps. **Great, the network performance on "up to 5 gigabit" is corresponding perfectly.**
4. Up to 10 Gigabit: **Download and upload the same as an instance running "up to 5 gigabit". It's not corresponding to what it should be.. 9 gigabit at least should be fine!**
5. Up to 25 Gigabit: **I can't believe.** **Download and upload network performance practically the SAME as "up to 5 gigabit". It should be at least 20-22 Gigabit.**
6. I'm almost sure that "25 Gigabit, 50 Gigabit, 75 Gigabit, 100 Gigabit will happen the same. It won't connect more than 4 Gigabit.

Could anyone explains what is going on? Is that normal? Do I need to make any settings to enhance network performance?

Hope to hear from the community,
Thanks a lot!!

Mat

Comment: Can you elaborate on the way you did the measurement?

Comment: Hello Dusan! I made these tests using speed test cli, via ssh directly from each server

Answer (score 4):

There appear to be several potential ssues at play, here.

Perhaps the most noteworthy is that the performance numbers in the specs are not *Internet* bandwidth, they're *Ethernet* bandwidth.

> Network traffic to the Internet is limited to 5 Gbps (full duplex).
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

You may counter that your destination is not "The Internet" because your test target is a system located in the same AWS region, but the traffic is still going through your VPC's Internet Gateway.

The next consideration is that the maximum performance potential for EC2 applies only within the same VPC, within a placement group, using private IP addresses, with multiple simultaneous traffic flows.

> Traffic to and from EC2 instances in the same or different Availability Zones within a region can now take advantage of up to 5 Gbps of bandwidth for single-flow traffic, or 25 Gbps of bandwidth for multi-flow traffic (a flow represents a single, point-to-point network connection) by using private IPv4 or IPv6 addresses as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html).
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/the-floodgates-are-open-increased-network-bandwidth-for-ec2-instances/

Before you can use a tool like this for benchmarking, you also need to be able to verify that the tool would, e.g., actually be able to accurately test the range of capabilities in question.

Speed test tools require a server on the other end that is capable of generating enough data to saturate the connection, and you presumably don't have a way of verifying that, though you might inquire about the tester's actual capabilities with Ookla.

You also need to verify that the tool isn't exhausting some other resource on the server, such as CPU, which might not manifest itself as 100% CPU utilization because the number of saturated cores won't exceed the number of threads running.

See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/ for bemchmarking guidelines, including using `iperf` on two machines to test the bandwidth between them.

Comment: Michael! How are you? Great to hear from you!

Well, as you mentioned about iperf... Thanks for this info. Well, I did this on the server that is running network up to 10 Gigabit and there’s a great news: I got 9,9 Gigabit :) amazing!!

Please, check the image: https://ibb.co/VTqkkPZ

I’d like to understand just a bit more:

What is the exactly the meaning on getting 9,9 Gigabit on iperf?

What I really don’t understand is that I can get about only 4 Gigabit on speedtest.net and on iperf I really can get up to 10 Gigabit.

Thanks for everything and I hope to hear about :)

Mat

Comment: Running a network speed test measures the performance between two machines by actually sending traffic between them, and measuring how much can be sent, so you're not just testing the speed of your machine's connection, you're also testing the speed of the other machine's connection as well as the speed of the network path between them.  With the speedtest.net tester, you don't know what the other machine is capable of or exactly what the path is between your server and theirs.  Test between a high bandwidth EC2 machine and a low one, and the result will always be limited by the lower one.

Comment: Oh well, great to know. So, when you say “Test between a high bandwidth EC2 machine and a low one, and the result will always be limited by the lower one”... In case, does it mean that if I do the test using an EC2 up to 10 Gigabit and the second one up to 5 Gigabit the result will be limited by the up to 5 gigabit? And if we want to get “the maximum network performance speed” both machines should have the same network performance? Example: Running an EC2 instance Up to 25 Gigabit (the second must also be Up to 25 Gigabit) ?

Comment: Great, bro! Just 2 mores questions and I’m more than satisfited. In case, as you see on the screen https://ibb.co/VTqkkPZ , I made an iperf test and got speed on 9.9 Gigabit speed performance. Question 1: When an iperf test results on 9.9 Gigabit connection what does it mean? It means 1.2gb/s down/up? 2nd question: I will only download/upload on that speed if the computer that Im downloading/uploading to has the same or better network than mine, right? (must be 9.9 or high)

Comment: Yes 8 giga*bits* per second is 1 giga*byte* per second, so 10 Gbit/s is 1.25 GB/s.  In any network interaction between two systems, the slowest of System A's connection, System B's connection, and all of the network components (switches, routers, WAN circuits, etc.) in between the two determines the absolute maximum speed... but in practice, it is slower for a single traffic flow.  You may also wish to familiarize yourself with the concept of [Bandwidth Delay Product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product), which can significantly impact apparent bandwidth over distance.

Comment: Perfect! I got everything! Tks a lot. Just a little point that came now: I created 2 instances of (m5dn.8xlarge) and 2 instances of (m5n.8xlarge) that amazons announces to be 25 Gigabit. I made an IPERF test with each one separately and both get maximum of 10 Gigabit/s. https://ibb.co/gDVLcxM Do you think amazon announces it with the wrong value?? BecauseI think IPERF is very accurate.

Comment: I believe achieving the full 25 gbit/s requires the two instances to be in the same Cluster Placement Group.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html  You probably will also need to configure iperf to use multiple flows, or to run multiple copies of it in parallel (on different ports), since there is still a 10 gbit/s flow limit.

Comment: Ohh, so I definitely need to create the instances in the same group placement, good. I am looking here when creating a placement group and there are 2 options (spread or partition) to choose. Which option should I select?

Comment: According to the docs, a "cluster" placement group is what you are looking for.

Comment: Great, tks a LOT!! I will try it here and talk to you after doing the tests :)

Comment: Getting an average speed of 10 Gigabit, 25 Gigabit.. or even more... I know this results can truely be reached on IPERF test. Is there any possibility to reach these same high speed values conecting my aws vps to another server that isn’t from amazon aws(that has actually the same network performance)? or reaching high speed is definitely restricted to tests inside amazon aws environment?

Comment: @mpgmateus  In general, one of the many limits to the performance of a TCP connection is:
Throughput <= EffectiveWindowSize/RoundTripTime
and if you have two systems which are "far" apart (large RTT) you need/want/may change the TCP settings - eg net.ipv4.tcp_[rw]mem - to increase the maximum TCP window size to compensate.  Lots more to it of course...

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on how your tool is testing speed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html

> Bandwidth for single-flow (5-tuple) traffic is limited to 5 Gbps when instances are not in the same cluster placement group.

I’m not sure exactly how the Speedtest CLI is implemented, but it’s not uncommon for tools like that to utilize a single flow. The following documentation indicates that at least the destination port is held constant during the test, and we know that the source and destination IP addresses will remain constant, as will the protocol (tcp). So if the source port isn’t varied, that’s a single 5-tuple, which is going to run into the 5Gpbs limit.

https://help.speedtest.net/hc/en-us/articles/360038679354-How-does-Speedtest-measure-my-network-speeds-

> The client establishes multiple connections with the server over port: 8080.

What you’d want to do is pick a traffic benchmarking tool that allows for multiple flows, or verify that Speedtest cli is actually opening up multiple source ports while it’s running. **I’d recommend iperf**; make sure to use the latest version.

The big takeaway here is that advertised bandwidth numbers are generally describing a best-case usage pattern, where the traffic being transmitted consists of large packets on many flows. Under the hood, there are systems that need to process this traffic, and generally each flow will be sticky to one processing core of that system/systems. The bulk of the work that they need to do is fixed per packet, so large packets mean more bandwidth utilized for less real work. And multiple flows means distribution over multiple processing cores, instead of bottlenecking on one.